# Multiple HTML Forms POST Data Open In New Tabs

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, post

I have multiple forms on one page that get populated dynamically from a Mysql database using PHP.

Each form posts the data to a new page that allows the user to "view more details" -- this page opens in a new tab.

Here is my problem - when a user clicks on "view more details" it opens in a new tab but if they go back and select another scholarship it opens in the same tab that was already open. I want the user to be able to open multiple tabs at once for each scholarship from the page.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tcanfarotta22/x64q0597/

Here is a sample form

```
    <div class='list' style='width:1750px; margin:0 auto;'>
  <form action='singleview.php' method='post' target='_new'>
    <table id='scholarship' style='float:left;' align='center'>
      <thead>
        <th class='head' colspan='3' style='text-align:center;'>University of Michigan--Dearborn
          <br>
          <br>Full Tuition
          <br>
          <br>Public
          <br>
          <br>
          <input type='hidden' name='id' value='ARLUJ'>
          <input type='submit' value='View More Details'>
          <br>(Will Open in a New Tab)</th>
      </thead>
  </form>
  </table>
</div>
<div class='list' style='width:1750px; margin:0 auto;'>
  <form action='singleview.php' method='post' target='_new'>
    <table id='scholarship' style='float:left;' align='center'>
      <thead>
        <th class='head' colspan='3' style='text-align:center;'>University of Michigan--Dearborn
          <br>
          <br>$1,500
          <br>
          <br>Public
          <br>
          <br>
          <input type='hidden' name='id' value='BNAOT'>
          <input type='submit' value='View More Details'>
          <br>(Will Open in a New Tab)</th>
      </thead>
  </form>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When user click then change (with javascript) the `target='_new'` as `target='_new2'` and then `target='_new3'` ... etc.

Comment: Yes, that did it. I added a unique id to each target after _new.

Answer (score 0):

Just put target='_blank' instead of "_new".